# Can not "prove" the limit of $n^{1/4}$ and $\ln^2(n)$

Tags: limits

I was trying to find the limit of $\frac{\ln^2(x)}{x^{1/4}}$ where $x$ goes to infinity. After applying L'Hospital two times, the result was $0$. So $x^{1/4}$ is increasing faster. Then I wrote a C program and run the for loop for very big numbers, $x^{1/4}$ never got bigger than $\ln^2(x)$. Where am I doing this wrong? Please help me.

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{(\ln(x))^2}{x^{1/4}}$$?

Comment: If $x=10^{40}$, $x^{1/4}=10^{10}$ and $(\ln x)^2=1600(\ln 10)^2$ which is much less than $10^{10}$.

Comment: $$\frac{(\ln x)^2}{x^{1/4}}=64\cdot\left(\frac{\ln(x^{1/8})}{x^{1/8}}\right)^2$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes I mean that

Comment: you must use L'Hospital twice to get the limit

Comment: Good news: there's nothing wrong with your mathematical solution for the limit question. Maybe there's a flaw in your C program? But then, this is not an appropriate question for this forum. And by the way, define "very big numbers". Most likely, they are not big enough yet.

Comment: Here's a trick you can try: graph $\ln(10^n\cdot x)^2/10^m$ and  $(10^n\cdot x)^{1/4}/10^m$ and vary the parameter $n$ until you can find the intersection (use $m$ to keep the curves within the screen). I get that $\ln(10^{9.7}\cdot 43)^2\approx(10^{9.7}\cdot 43)^{1/4}$ (this is a pretty big number, and like the other commenters have said, your numbers might not have been big enough) https://imgur.com/kM6RS1H

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those cases where basic numerical evidence might be a bit misleading. In fact, the function $x \mapsto \ln^2 x / x^{1/4}$ is increasing from $x = 1$ to $x = e^8 \approx 3000$ and decreases rather slowly after that. For example if $x = 10^{10}$, then the function value is still rather large, roughly $1.68$.

It takes extremely large numbers to witness that this is in fact going to zero - and depending on your C implementation, it might well take numbers that are too large for the program to use.

---

On the other hand, if we take $x = e^N$, for example, then

$$\frac{\ln^2 x}{x^{1/4}} = \frac{N^2}{e^{N/4}}$$

Now this is a bit easier for you to handle numerically, since we can use *much* larger values for $x$ than a `double`  would allow.

For example, if $N = 100$, then $10^4 / e^{25}$ is quite small. A really terrible hand-estimate using $e > 2$ shows that $e^{25} > (2^{10})^{2.5} > 10^{7.5}$. Hence, the function value is at most $10^{-3.5} < 0.001.$

Answer (score 1):

set $f:(0,\infty)\mapsto \Bbb R$ , $f(x)=\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\sqrt[4]{x}}$

if you take the derivative you will get $f'(x)=-\dfrac{\left(\ln\left(x\right)-8\right)\ln\left(x\right)}{4x^\frac{5}{4}}$ and here you can find the max/min points:$$0=-\dfrac{\left(\ln\left(x\right)-8\right)\ln\left(x\right)}{4x^\frac{5}{4}}\\0=\left(\ln(x)-8\right)\ln(x)$$

you have $2$ answers, you can check and find that $x=1$ is minimum and $x=e^8$ is maximum, so the function is increasing between $1$ and $e^8(\approx2980)$ and decreasing before and after it

Answer (score 0):

It can be written as 
$$\frac{\ln ^2x}{x^{\tfrac14}}=\biggl(\frac{\ln  x}{x^{1/8}}\biggr)^{\!2}$$
and setting $\,t=x^{1/8}$, it comes down to a standard high school limit:
$$\biggl(\frac{\ln(t^8)}{t}\biggr)^{\!2}=2^6\biggl(\frac{\ln t}{t}\biggr)^{\!2}.$$

*Edit:*

For $n=2$, we have $\,2^{2/4}=\sqrt 2\approx 1.414>\ln^22\approx 1.386$.

Comment: Nice approach! But this answer doesn't address the OP's question at all. They already found the value of the limit.

Comment: @zipirovich: The question seems to have been modified…